# porque mi bucle while no funciona hasta 3

Tags: java, netbeans

hola amigos tengo un pequeño problema. este programa consiste en pedirle la calve al usuario la cual es 1234, si el usuario se equivoca tres veces al digitar la clave el sistema termina de lo contrario despliega un output: Clave exitosa.

el problema que tengo es que si digito la clave invalida apropósito 2 veces y a la tercera vez digito la clave correcta el sistema termina y se supone que mi variable contador me debe dar hasta tres intentos. Claro que si le digo a mi variable contador que incremente hasta 4 vuelvo a digitar apropósito la clave erronea 2 veces y a la tercera vez la clave correcta me da clave exitosa.

```
public class CicloWhile {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int clave=0,contador=0;
    
    while(clave!=1234){
    System.out.println("Digita la clave");
    clave=sc.nextInt();
    contador ++;
    if(clave!=1234){ System.err.println("Clave invalida.");}
    
    if(contador==3){ System.err.println("has acabado con el numero de intentos");break;}
    else if(clave==1234){ System.out.println("Clave exitosa");}
    
    }
    
    
}
}
```

Comment: Se equivoque o no, incrementas el contador; y evalúas el contador antes de validar la clave, sin importar si es correcta. ¿Cuál es la prioridad, validar la clave o contar los intentos?.

Comment: Hazlo con un **ciclo *for***. El ciclo *while* se utiliza generalmente cuando no se conoce un número predeterminado y exacto de cuántas veces se va a realizar el proceso, en cambio, el ciclo *for* es exactamente para eso

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para comenzar fue un poco dificil comprender tu syntaxis asi que la ordene un poco.

Supongo que lo que intentas hacer es un login, por lo tanto, los cambios que realice fueron los siguientes:

[1] Agregue el contador a las claves ingresadas incorrectamente
[2] Ordene las sentencias por orden logico con el fin de que al ingresar incorrectamente la clave numero 3 tu programa termine.

Como recomendacion personal, el libro Clean Architecture de Robert C. Martin puede ser de mucha utilidad. Lo digo por experiencia propia.

Si te sirvio hazmelo saber y sino tambien

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CicloWhile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);           
        int contador = 0;
       
        while(true){
        
            System.out.println("Digita la clave");
            int clave = sc.nextInt();
            
            if(clave == 1234){
                System.out.println("Clave éxitosa");
                break;
            }
            else {
                System.err.println("Clave invalida.");
                contador ++;
            }
            
            if(contador == 3){ 
                System.err.println("Has acabado con el numero de intentos");
                break;
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Es un ciclo infinito, tu variable contador debe estar fuera del ``while`` igual la variable ``sc`` solo debe instanciar 1 vez

Comment: gracias, si me sirvio mucho

Answer (score 1):

El problema es el orden de tu código en las siguientes lineas

```
if(clave!=1234){ System.err.println("Clave invalida.");}
    
if(contador==3){ System.err.println("has acabado con el numero de intentos");break;}
else if(clave==1234){ System.out.println("Clave exitosa");}
```

La razón, cuando el contador llega a 3 intentos tu código dice que tiene que escribir el mensaje `has acabado con el numero de intentos`, entonces debes cambiar el orden de tus condicionales.
Te dejo el código con las correcciones.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int clave,contador=1;       
        System.out.print("Digita la clave :");        
        clave=sc.nextInt();       
                
        while(contador<=3){            
            if(clave==1234){ 
                System.out.println("Clave exitosa");
                break;                
            }
            else{
                System.err.println("Clave invalida.");
                
                if(contador==3)
                {
                    System.out.println("Alcanzó el Nº de intentos máximo");
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.print("Digita la clave :");
                    clave=sc.nextInt();
                }
                contador++;
            }           
        }
    }
```

Comment: esta opción es muy buena. gracias